# Integrate jenkins and iib runtime

Tags: jenkins, github, centos7, ibm-integration-bus

i want to setup build automation for IIB deployment using jenkins and enterprise github as a code repository.in my case, i have jenkins and iib runtime on different servers.

1. how do jenkins can run the IIB related run time commands and toolkit commands like mqsicreatebar in another server ?
2. is there any good approach for the above scenario ?
3. instead of building all IIb applications, i want to build only the project that was pushed to gitlab using post-receive hook script and generate environment specific bar files. ( using gitlab webhooks now)

Comment: Personally I'd add something like Ansible into the mix. In the CICD solution I built we run Jenkins and Ansible on our CICD Server. Jenkins coordinates the execution of the playbooks and Ansible takes care of the execution of IIB commands on the target IIB systems.

Comment: You can setup remote Jenkins agents on your target system but you need to deploy and manage the software for those agents. It's why I chose Ansible it self deploys for the duration of the playbooks, it does require Python on the target system but almost all Linux distros' come with Python these days.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. ill go and check if ansible is available in our environment :-)

Comment: Do beware that Ansible has a steep learning curve but there are quite a few useful examples and questions out there.

Comment: I fully understand your goals, I am trying to setup such configuration on my side as well. I encountered two major issues with IIB and github already : 1) Github is good at versioning code, but in IIB cases, it is mostly XML, and resolving conflict and creating branches is almost impossible. 2) We have to create a different repository for each application, which was already refused by the team administrating Github ... So I'm a bit stuck since we are still on SVN. But for point 1, just install IIB on this server, it will allow you to launch the commands

Comment: Hi @Jérém , thank u for reply. i'm lucky for point 2. :-) i got approval for creating repository for each application .. but im stuck at repository for library.  since all applications refer common shared libraries, i need to find a way to checkout common library repositories along with the appication repository that has actual change so that my jenkins workspace has applicaton and all referenced libraries for a successful build.

Comment: maven or any other dependency management tool might do the trick

Comment: Did anyone able to acheive below point 1?                                             1) how do jenkins can run the IIB related run time commands and toolkit commands like mqsicreatebar in another server ?

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.ibm.com/integration/blog/2018/12/03/iib-v9-v10-continuous-integration-maven-jenkins/